# Is there a way to make setInterval fire only after a certain amount of time has passed?

Tags: javascript

I have

```
var slideIn1 = setInterval(slideBarIn1, 1)
```

I also have

```
var slideIn2 = setInterval(slideBarIn2, 1)
```

I would like the second setInterval to take affect a few seconds after clearInterval is used on slideIn1.
I tried using setTimeout to call the second setInterval after a few seconds, but setInterval fires upon page load...Any suggestions?

```
function slideBarIn1(){
    barPosition1 = barPosition1 - 0.7;
    verticalBar.style.left = barPosition1+"px";

    if (barPosition1 < (-320)) {
        clearInterval(slideIn1);
    }   
}

function slideBarIn2(){
    barPosition2 = barPosition2 - 0.7;
    horizontalBar.style.top = barPosition2+"px";

    if (barPosition2 < (-320)) {
        clearInterval(slideIn2);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? (see [mcve]). Why not just call `setInterval(slideBarIn2, 1)` when you call `clearInterval`?

Comment: How can I call setInterval(slideBarIn2, 1) with clearInterval? I posted the functions above. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just put the line `slideIn2 = setInterval(slideBarIn2, 1);` directly after `clearInterval(slideIn1);`. Still declare `slideIn2` in global scope, i.e. keep `var slideIn2;`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that worked. Is there any way I could delay setInterval(slideBarIn2, 1) a few seconds after clearInterval(slideIn1)? Just so it doesnt trigger immediately after. I realize I could just decrease the value in the conditional statement, but that doesnt seem too efficient.

Comment: As you mentioned yourself,  you can use `setTimeout`.

Comment: Ahh right, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to:
1) Wait for the page to load.
2) Wait 1 second.
3) Execute slideBarIn1.
4) Wait 1 second.
5) Execute slideBarIn2.
6) Wait (unspecified) second(s).
7) Go back to step 3 - Execute slideBarIn1.

I would recommend switching from using setInterval or the combination of setInterval and setTimeout, and replace them with strategically placed 'setTimeout's.

Below is an example that should alternate between slideBarIn1 and slideBarIn2 with 1 second delays in between.

```js
/* Wait until page loaded and then start the first sequence */
window.onload = function() {
// Execute slideBarIn1 in 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
    setTimeout(slideBarIn1, 1000); 
};
function slideBarIn1() {
    //Do whatever slideBarIn1 needs to do
    //And then, before leaving this function
    // start a timer for slideBarIn2
    setTimeout(slideBarIn2, 1000);
}
const delayBetweenTwoAndOne = 1000; // set to zero for no delay
function slideBarIn2() {
    // Do whatever slideBarIn2 needs to do
    // If you wish to keep the loop going, 
    // you can now set another timer for slideBarIn1
    setTimeout(slideBarIn1, delayBetweenTwoAndOne); 
}
```